# How would I keep the slash in my $domain when using wpmu_create_blog to create a site

Tags: php, wordpress, function, dns, wpmu

I am currently working on an automated site creation function on my local installation of wordpress. In essence, a form is filled out on an already existing site and that info is pulled to create a new site automatically via an endpoint that activates some queries. So far I have been able to successfully pull the information into an array and then pass that to the `wpmu_create_blog` function. The issue is that the `$domain` isn't being called correctly(that is to say, how I intend it to be called), the '/' is lost between 'localhost' and 'wordpress'.

```
public function create_endpoint($request) {
        $key = $request['key'];
        if ($this->validate_key($key)) {
          $newsite = array (
                $title = $request['name'],
                $path = $request['slug'],
                $admin_user = $request['admin_user'],
              );
                $domain = 'localhost/wordpress';
                $site_id = get_blog_id_from_url($domain, $path);
                $user_id = get_user_by('login', $admin_user);
                  if ( !empty($title) and !empty($domain) and !empty($path) and empty($user_id) ) {
                    return wpmu_create_blog($domain, $path, $title, $user_id, $site_id);
                  }
                  else {
                    return "Not enough information";
                  }
        }
         else {
            return $this->invalid_key_message;
        }
    }
```

Everything but the domain being called as intended is working as intended. This is also just the static prototype, my end goal is that this is entirely dynamic including the `$domain` variable.

I'm just totally lost on where to go from here. I've tried some appendage stuff and moving syntax around in all types of ways but keep hitting a wall. Any input or suggestions are happily accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution implemented. In the array `$path` has been changed to `$slug` (use of slug is specific to my code). The `$domain` now only calls 'localhost' and I create `$path` using plain text the 'wordpress' and then add the slug via a `$request`.

```
  $newsite = array (
                $title = $request['name'],
                $slug = $request['slug'],
                $admin_user = $request['admin_user'],
              );
                $domain = 'localhost';
                $path = 'wordpress/'.$request['slug'];
```